# Returning malloc from a function in C

Tags: c

I have been trying to return a malloc from a function for three days now, however without joy.

my code is as follows what i am trying to do is pass two one dimensional array and perform matrix calculation, then return the result in a two dimensional array. the code is as follows:

```
int **func1(numrow, numcol, *temp, *word){

int  i, c, d;
int **pointer;

pointer = (int**)malloc( numrow * sizeof(int*);

        for(i=0; i<numrow; i++){
           pointer[i] = (int*)malloc( numcol * sizeof(int*) );    
        }

        for ( c = 0 ; c < numrow ; c++ )
            for ( d = 0 ; d < numcol ; d++ )
                    pointer[c][d] =( (temp[c] - word[r]) * (temp[c] - word[r])     );   

    return pointer;

}

int main(){

int **poi, r, c, numcol, numrow;
int templet[8] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 4, 4 };
int newWord[8] = {1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 5, 0, 0 };

printf("please enter the number of rows:\n");
scanf("%d%d",&numrow, &numcol);

    poi = func1(numrow, numcol, templet, newWord );


        for(r=0; r<numrow; r++)
            for(c=0; c< numrow; c++)

                printf("%d\n",*(*(poi + r) + c));


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Cool story, but do you have an actual question? Obviously aside from your lack of a closing paren on the malloc line?

Comment: This sounds strange: scanf("%d%d",&numrow, &numcol); How can scanf() understand where a number finishes and the next one begins?

Comment: Also, shouldn't your second malloc allocate `int` instead of `int *`?

Comment: `int **func1(numrow, numcol, *temp, *word){` this will not compile because the parameters don't have a declared type.

Comment: @Jack scanf stops at and skips blanks.

Comment: There's a closing parenthesis missing in `pointer = (int**)malloc( numrow * sizeof(int*);`. You should post compilable code.

Comment: @AlterMann It would be more useful to say that it won't compile *because the parameters don't have a declared type*.

Comment: @ciphermagi, good point, edited ;)

Comment: This code is invalid C in many ways. What did your compiler report? Did you listen to what it had to say? Why don't you show us the error messages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First change your function declarator to

```
int **func1(int numrow, int numcol, int *temp, int *word)
```

then replace `r` by `d` in

```
pointer[c][d] =( (temp[c] - word[r]) * (temp[c] - word[r]));
```

and finally

```
printf("%d\n",*(*(poi + r) + c));
```

to

```
printf("%d\n",poi[r][c]);
```

Corrected code:

```
int **func1(int numrow, int numcol, int *temp, int *word) {

int  i, c, d;
int **pointer;

pointer = malloc(numrow * sizeof(int*));

    for (i = 0; i < numrow; i++){
       pointer[i] = malloc(numcol * sizeof(int));
    }

    for ( c = 0 ; c < numrow ; c++ )
        for ( d = 0 ; d < numcol ; d++ )
                pointer[c][d] =( (temp[c] - word[d]) * (temp[c] - word[d]));

    return pointer;
}

int main(void){
    int **poi, r, c, numcol, numrow;
    int templet[8] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 4, 4 };
    int newWord[8] = {1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 5, 0, 0 };

    printf("please enter the number of rows and columns:\n");
    scanf("%d%d", &numrow, &numcol);
    poi = func1(numrow, numcol, templet, newWord);
    for (r = 0; r < numrow; r++)
        for(c = 0; c  numrow; c++)
            printf("%d\n",poi[r][c]);
        return 0;
}
```

---

Possible suggestions:

> - Learn to indent code properly.
> - Debug your code many times as possible before asking here.
> - **Turn on your compiler warnings** (like `-Werror`, `-pedantic` etc).

Comment: Thanks alot to all of you. please bare with me case am very new to C. this may look simple to you guys but it is surely french to me.

Comment: And as always, one should check number of items read on `scanf` and validate `malloc`. OP also asks user to enter number of rows, but read rows + columns ...

Answer (score -1):

Minor Changes Required in your Code full code would be this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int **func1(int numrow, int numcol, int *temp, int *word){  
    int  i, c, d;
    int **pointer;

    pointer = (int**)malloc( numrow * sizeof(int*));

    for(i=0; i<numrow; i++){
        pointer[i] = (int*)malloc( numcol * sizeof(int*) );    
    }

    for ( c = 0 ; c < numrow ; c++ ){
        for ( d = 0 ; d < numcol ; d++ ){
            pointer[c][d] =( (temp[c] - word[d]) * (temp[c] - word[d])     );
        }
    }
    return pointer;
}

int main(){

    int **poi, r, c, numcol, numrow;
    int templet[8] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 4, 4 };
    int newWord[8] = {1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 5, 0, 0 };

    printf("please enter the number of rows:\n");
    scanf("%d%d",&numrow, &numcol);

    poi = func1(numrow, numcol, templet, newWord );


        for(r=0; r<numrow; r++){
            for(c=0; c< numrow; c++){
                printf("%d\n",poi[r][c]); 
            }
        }
    return 0;
}
```